# SQL combine and join row data with same Table

Tags: mysql, sql

My SQL Query

```
SELECT emp_location, emp_system_name, emp_compName, tran_type_code, emp_morn_checkin, emp_ot_checkin, emp_ot_checkout, over_time, ontime, updated_by
FROM timesheet_tran
WHERE emp_id =  'TMSTEST'
AND tran_as_of_date =  '04/02/14'
```

Returns data as

[image: SQL Structure]

I want to find a way to combine and display data

Like

```
emp_location -- emp_system_name -- morn_check_OTM -- mor_check_DLY -- overtime_OTM --overtime_OT
AMK               ::1                8.45               8.38            1:15           6:30
```

My SQL knowledge , cant do this :(

Comment: What about `tran_type_code` which value do you want to select `OTM` or `DLY` or `OT` or any value??

Comment: what are the rules to combine the entries? do calculations need to happen or only select based on tran_type_code ?

Comment: the vaules need to be in one row .. morn_check_OTM , mor_check_DLY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is *pivot* rows into columns, unfortunately MySQL doesn't have a native pivot table operator, but you can use the `CASE` expression to do so:

```
SELECT 
  emp_location, 
  emp_system_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN tran_type_code = 'OTM' THEN emp_morn_checkin END) AS morn_check_OTM,
  MAX(CASE WHEN tran_type_code = 'DLY' THEN emp_morn_checkin END) AS morn_check_DLY,
  MAX(CASE WHEN tran_type_code = 'OT' THEN emp_morn_checkin END) AS morn_check_OT,
  MAX(CASE WHEN tran_type_code = 'OTM' THEN over_time END) AS over_time_OTM,
  MAX(CASE WHEN tran_type_code = 'DLY' THEN over_time END) AS over_time_DLY,
  MAX(CASE WHEN tran_type_code = 'OT' THEN over_time END) AS over_time_OT
FROM timesheet_tran
WHERE emp_id =  'TMSTEST'
AND tran_as_of_date =  '04/02/14'
GROUP BY emp_location, emp_system_name;
```

Comment: From where do we find People like U ..:) cheers Works like Charm

Comment: from were do you know all this stuff ?

Comment: @epynic From here, from stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using concat(a, '---',b,c,d,) the way you want

Comment: concat(emp_location, '--', emp_system_name, '--' ,morn_check_OTM ,'--' ,mor_check_DLY, '--', overtime_OTM ,'--',overtime_OT)

Comment: yes but how can i combine the resultant to one single row